# ElasticBeanstalk CLI deploy command succeeds silently, but does not deploy

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gitlab-ci

I'm having an odd issue with the `awsebcli` package when running it on Gitlab's pipeline CI system.

When I run `eb deploy` locally, the command succeeds (or fails) much as expected. When I run it as part of the CD scripts I've written, it runs successfully (i.e. returns an exit code of 0) but doesn't actually trigger the deployment. No errors are returned - in fact there's no text output from the command at all.

Can anyone suggest what could be going wrong here?

Comment: What's the exit code you see after `eb deploy` locally? Can you execute a a `echo $?` immediately after to check?

Comment: I ran into this also... I'm doing a batch deploy and it exits the cli command after the first batch and continues the deploy in the console. Did you ever find out anything more about this?